# python3 get parameter from command terminal and print input out

Tags: python, linux, unix, input

```
lines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    lines.append(line)
    print(line, end='')
```

[image]

My question, how can I get 2 into the program and print out content of input.txt at the same time? So far, it would get 2 as a file name and try to open it as a file, not as expected. You see in the pic.

Comment: `sys.argv` is your friend.

Comment: yes. but I cannot get input.txt

Comment: It seems < doesn't work in this way.

Comment: `input.txt` is redirected to the standard input stream. `2` is going into `argv`.

Comment: but 2 is regarded as a file name as well now. but it is just a arg like -l of ls..

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `input.txt` file can be accesed using the `sys.stdin` file handle from inside python.
The arguments must be accesed using the `sys.argv` array.

Here is a sample script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
arg=sys.argv[1] #take first argument
lines=[]
for line in sys.stdin:
  lines.append(line) # save line from stdin to the array. Watch out for memory usage.


print arg
print lines
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eugene already pointed out, in your command:

```
./whale.py '2' < input.txt
```

> `input.txt` is redirected to the standard input stream. `2` is going
>   into argv.

The error you got was probably because somehow your script thought `argv[1]` was the file to open.

try this:

```
import sys
print "this is sys.argv: {}".format(sys.argv[1])
print "below is STDIN:"
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```